# Color excel plot by field

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have data which looks like this:

```
Type, X, Y
Foo, 1.2, 3.4
Foo, 3.2, 8.5
Bar, 2.3, 8.4
Baz, 3.4, 5.3
```

I would like to make a scatter plot of the x and y columns, and color the dots by the type column.  There are over 2000 rows and 20-30 types, so creating series manually will be difficult.

It looks like [Plotting data in excel grouped by type](https://superuser.com/questions/884206/plotting-data-in-excel-grouped-by-type) almost does what I want, except I cannot see how to get a scatter plot instead of a bar chart.

I can easily make a scatter plot of the data, but everything then shows up as one color.

Bonus points if the solution allows me to easily filter which data is shown.

I am running Excel for Mac 16.33.

Comment: Take a look at [Excel - How can I make a scatter plot which colors by a third column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124103/excel-how-can-i-make-a-scatter-plot-which-colors-by-a-third-column), I think this does everything you need?

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple formulas to split the column of Y values into three columns for Foo, Bar, and Baz. In the data range below, the formula in D2, and filled into the whole range D2:F5, is

```
=IF($A2=D$1,$C2,NA())
```

Then select the highlighted range and make a scatter chart by columns (I got something strange at first and had to click *Switch Rows and Columns*).

[image]

Comment: That would work, although having to create 20-30 additional columns will be annoying.